# Can I forbid the creation of files with certain permissions?

Tags: rename, cp, group

I have a directory with a certain group ID, and I only want files with the same ID to be in that directory.

So I set the SGID bit on that directory, so that everytime a file is created inside it, it gets the correct ID. Commands like cp or touch are fine now. The problem is that if someone uses mv to move a file inside the directory, its group ID isn't set to that of the directory.

I do not want that to happen.

Comment: I'm afraid such functionality isn't in the kernel. If `chown` running as a cron job out of question, you may use an inotify based application to change the ownership selectively.

Comment: What is your operating system, distribution, major/minor? There might be specific ways to accomplish that goal.

Comment: @Nils: newest CentOS

Comment: That is CentOS 6.4? Good. My current playground...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to accomplish this using just plain read/write/execute permissions that are on files/directories. However you can use access control lists (acls) - see [man acl](http://linux.die.net/man/5/acl) for info on how they work - and the [setfacl](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/setfacl1.html) command in particular to set permissions.

For example:

```
$ setfacl -Rm u:foo:rwX,d:u:foo:rwX test
```

to modify the current ACL as well as the default. I believe "d:" only affects the (d)efault ACL of directories and leaves files untouched. Then, if you create a new file in the directory, it inherits the ACL of its parent directory via the default.

#### References

- [How does one get setfacl to set ACL permissions recursively on Ubuntu 9.04 server edition?](https://serverfault.com/questions/2736/how-does-one-get-setfacl-to-set-acl-permissions-recursively-on-ubuntu-9-04-serve)
- [Disable Linux File Permissions for a tree](https://superuser.com/questions/504243/disable-linux-file-permissions-for-a-tree)

Comment: I'm afraid the default ACLs won't help in this case - they just cover the same situation as the SGID bit on a directory on the ACL side (i.e., only creation of a new file).

Answer (score 0):

```
chown root $MYDIR
chmod ug+rw,o=- $MYDIR
```

Now you need to watch $MYDIR - if a file is being changed there, you should notice:

You could put this into a loop:

```
sleep 60
touch --reference $MYDIR /dev/shm/lastcheck_mydir
find $MYDIR -type f -anewer /dev/shm/lastcheck_mydir
```

Now if `find` has found new files, you can act upon it - like

```
find $MYDIR -type f -anewer /dev/shm/lastcheck_mydir -exec chgrp $MYGID {} \;
```

Comment: Users who are supposed to create files in the directory belong to the same group the directory is set to. The group permissions are `rws`. I do not have root permissions.

Comment: @bug Updated my answer with a different solution

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, how does FTP behave in this case? It should be impossible to just `move` a file with FTP, they're always `copied`. Could FTP be the solution?